# oracle regex - what is the wildcard character

Tags: regex, oracle

How do I select wild card in oracle regex, I've tried:

```
select regexp_count(ccc,'TS*231') 
from (select some_clob as ccc from table);
```

CLOB for example:

```
INDEX (LOB):                         SYS_IL0000124648C00002$$
TABLE NAME:                          DR#IDX_INE0009$R
TABLESPACE NAME:                     TS_M00000_0000000231_DEF_IDX
BLOCKS ALLOCATED:                                                        8
BLOCKS USED:                                                             4
BYTES ALLOCATED:                                         65,536 (64.00 KB)
BYTES USED:                                              32,768 (32.00 KB)
```

Currently this query above on that CLOB return 0 instead of 1. I've also tried instead of `*` - `.` and `%`.

Comment: Wildcard in regexp is `.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Any character' in Oracle regular expressions is the dot (`.`), as it is in most if not all regex dialects. To match any number of any character, use `.*` – again, as usual in regular expressions.